# Filter line geometry with two points

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a table of lines with their geoinformation in PostGIS. All of them are part of one roadline.

In QGIS, I want to query all geo coordinates that are included between two random points on the road.

Is it possible?

Comment: From definition - line is an infinite set of points(...) - are U sure you need to fetch infinite set of coordinates?

Comment: Oh. sorry for unclear formulation. It must be line segment not just line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple resolution is to merge (ST_Union, ST_Merge, ST_LineMerge, ST_Collect) this road (by number or any other property) segments into one line, split (ST_Split) it in this two points than select (ST_Intersects) only part which intersects with two points.

Comment: Nice answer... Why do I have the impression that I know it from upwork?

Comment: "If path have to include more than one different roads you need PGRouting" ;)